# LocalFile.php: Could not find data for image 'MediaWiki.pdf'

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have a MediaWiki 1.28.0 on a FreeBSD 11.0 installed.

When I try to upload a pdf (via the Special:Upload page), I am greeted with the following error message:

```
/index.php?title=Special:Upload MWException from line 425 
of /usr/local/www/data/includes/filerepo/file/LocalFile.php:
Could not find data for image 'MediaWiki.pdf'

Backtrace:

#0 /usr/local/www/wiki-01.ocn.sh/data/includes/filerepo
/file/LocalFile.php(553): LocalFile->loadExtraFromDB()
...
```

I can comment the function `loadExtraFromDB()` on line 553 of LocalFile.php, as written on the [wikimedia bugtracker](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T50700). This is just a workaround though and I end up having no thumbnails on the uploaded PDFs.

Has someone had that error and solved it? If so, how? I would really like to properly upload PDFs again :D

Comment: The bug tracker is probably a better place to get a bug fixed than StackOverflow. If you are looking for a quick workaround, you can wrap the call in a try-catch and throw the exception away.

Comment: Thanks, that is a better idea than my workaround, even though not perfect.